# Vue jest test for algorithm

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I have a component that look like this. How would I write a vue jest test to satisfy these conditions?

```html
<template>
  <div align="center">
    <button @click="Tests()">Tests</button>
    <button @click="Benchmark()">Benchmark</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      result: null,
    };
  },
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },

};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`@vue/test-utils`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/), you could [`shallowMount`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#shallowmount) the component to get a wrapper, and then access `smallestInt()` and `result` via the [`vm`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#vm) property of the wrapper:

```js
// MyComponent.spec.js
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent.vue'
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'

describe('MyComponent.smallestInt()', () => {
  it('case 1', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent)
    const A = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2]
    wrapper.vm.smallestInt(A)
    expect(wrapper.vm.result).toBe(5)
  })

  it('case 2', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent)
    const A = [-1, -3]
    wrapper.vm.smallestInt(A)
    expect(wrapper.vm.result).toBe(1)
  })
})
```